# CMake express the "greater or equal" statement

Tags: cmake

I know that in CMake I can check for the compiler version like this

```
if(MSVC_VERSION LESS 1700)
... // MSVC is lower than MSVC2012
```

but how do I express this in CMake syntax?

```
if(MSVC_VERSION GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO 1700)
... // MSVC greater or equal to MSVC2012
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Update for CMake 3.7 and later:**

CMake 3.7 [introduced a couple of new comparisons](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/release/3.7.html#commands) for `if`, among them `GREATER_EQUAL`:

```
if(MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL 1700)
    [...]
```

---

**Original answer for older CMake versions:**

```
if((MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1700) OR (MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1700))
  [...]
```

Or probably better, as it avoids repeating the condition:

```
if(NOT (MSVC_VERSION LESS 1700))
  [...]
```

Comment: All right, so there's no built-in keyword for that, that's a pity but I'll use your way. Thanks!

Comment: Right. Unfortunately CMake is quite minimalistic in certain places and this is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use `VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL`? (This was also introduced in CMake 3.7.)

I.e.:

```
if (MSVC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 1700)
# [...]
```

VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL and VERSION_LESS_EQUAL also support multipart version identifiers, such as 14.1.0, comparing these correctly as well.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.7 GREATER_EQUAL and LESS_EQUAL were introduced.